# How do I find out the size of a Canvas text object in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to create some text in a canvas:

```
myText = self.canvas.create_text(5, 5, anchor=NW, text="TEST")
```

Now how do I find the width and height of `myText`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
bounds = self.canvas.bbox(myText)  # returns a tuple like (x1, y1, x2, y2)
width = bounds[2] - bounds[0]
height = bounds[3] - bounds[1]
```

See the [TkInter reference](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas-methods.html).

Comment: In newer versions of tkinter you can provide an "angle" to create_text. If angle != 0 your solution is not correct anymore, because the bbox fits the whole rotated text.
In this case or generally you can use the font-metrics: `f=self.canvas.itemcget(myText, "font")
font = tk.font.Font(font=font.split(" "))
height = font.metrics("linespace")`

Answer (score 4):

This method seemed to work well if  all you are interested in is the width and height of the canvas being considered, using the bounds of the box and then checking the differential works just as well if you want to do it that way.

```
width = myText.winfo_width()  
height = myText.winfo_height()
```

Comment: `myText`, at least in the given example is an `int`. The lines you gave would only cause an **AttributeError** to be raised.

Comment: Wondering why this is upvoted so much since the comment above is correct: I'm just getting attribute errors.

Comment: This works in case `myText` is a widget. But **myText is not a separate widget but an id of an item in a Canvas** (i.e. an integer which refers to an item of the Canvas). You are trying to use the `.winfo_width()` method on that integer => you get AttributeError.